# Do Chica and Freddy do the same things?

Tags: five-nights-at-freddys

It seems that Chica (Right door) and Freddy (also right door) take almost identical paths, and appear at the same door. Apart from Freddy coming out when the power is out, what differences do Chica and Freddy have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no differences; everything wants to kill you.

The only thing significantly different about Freddy is that he will not appear at the door like Chica or Bonnie (in the camera's blind spots).

For a full rundown on his "behaviour", the [wiki](http://five-nights-at-freddys.wikia.com/wiki/Freddy_Fazbear) has a detailed description of his path, key events, and tactics.